# The slam_toolbox for ROS2 foxy does not publish the topic pose

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I notice that the slam_toolbox for ROS2 foxy does not publish the topic pose (https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox/tree/foxy-devel). I have confirmed it on my own virtual machine with the apt-get package. As far as I know, SLAM means mapping and localization. Where does the robot pose goes if the toolbox doesn't publish it? Can I get it from the TF?
May I use the pose map->Odom->base_link? Is it the same pose published on the pose topic for ROS galactic, humble and rolling?

A similar question can be found on [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/409825/slam_toolbox-no-pose-topic-published/).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411147/the-slam_toolbox-for-ros2-foxy-does-not-publish-the-topic-pose./) by [BlueBird](https://answers.ros.org/users/98868/bluebird/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2023-01-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2023-01-09**:
Don't cross post (https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox/issues/564).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can see [here](https://automaticaddison.com/sensor-fusion-using-the-robot-localization-package-ros-2/) on the picture below, where the robot info goes.

[image: image description]

Yes, you can get it from `/tf` topic.

You can read more about the state estimate here, in Nav2 documentation:

- https://navigation.ros.org/concepts/index.html?highlight=odom#state-estimation

The goal of odometry is to provide a smooth and continuous local frame based on the robot's motion. However, it will drift over time as errors accumulate.

On the other side, transformation `map->odom` can "jump" between values, but is usually more precise - it is provided by the positioning system (localization, mapping, SLAM).

I don't know about any differences between the mentioned versions of ROS2 (Foxy, Galactic, Humble) - the interface is really similar or overall the same.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2023-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2